# Benchmarking GHC compilation times

Tags: performance, haskell, build, ghc

My Haskell program takes too long to compile.

By that, I mean: It's been over a year since I've been able to compile with -O1. Last time I tried, I set up a 64gb server just to compile my program, and let it run overnight. It ran out of memory.

I'm about to embark on some big re-engineering changes which I hope will speed up compilation times, but first I need to know what's taking so long, and get some good measurements so I can track progress.

I currently have two ideas for how to do this:

1. Cover my program in flags so I can try compiling different pieces and timing
   them.
2. Writing a wrapper program for `stack build` that looks for lines like "[75 of 83] Compiling ," and times how long between them.

(1) sounds really ugly, and I don't expect (2) to give good numbers because of imprecision and because of cross-module compilation. Anyone have better ideas?

Comment: If you're running out of memory then you are hitting some bad asymptotics in GHC and (2) would probably help, especially if you can look at your modules as a dependency tree. (1) also sounds like what I would do TBH. If you can identify any of the slowness or get test cases you should definitely report them to GHC trac.

Comment: 4 years ago, in a predecessor to this project, I did identify one source of slowness, related to typeclass resolution involving Generic. It had already been reported in trac. To my knowledge, that performance issue has still not been fixed.

I wound up deleting that part of the code. 4 years later, my code is still missing NFData instances.

Comment: How would I view the dependency tree of my modules, and how would that help compared to suggestion (2) without dependency info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better and easier than watching text output, I realized I could simply look at the timestamps on files in the build folder.

This command gives me a nice list of build files sorted by timestamp, so I can roughly tell how long it spent on each:

```
ls -l -c -T -R .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/<source folder> | grep "rw" | grep "\." | awk '{print $8,$10}' | sort
```